# Сложное предложение с разными видами связи

Tags: синтаксис

На сайте РусОлимп сказано следующее:

Часто сложные предложения с разными видами связи членятся на две или несколько частей (блоков), соединённых с помощью сочинительных союзов или бессоюзно; а каждая часть по структуре представляет собой либо сложноподчинённое предложение, либо простое.

Но возьмем это предложение.

Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, где стояли наши лошади, посмотреть, есть ли у них корм, и притом осторожность никогда не мешает...

Это сложное предложение с разными видами связи: бессоюзной, подчинительной, и сочинительной.  Состоит из трех блоков, связанных бессоюзно и сочинительной связью.
Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, где стояли наши лошади - I блок, II блок(придаточное изъяснительное) - посмотреть, есть ли у них корм, и притом осторожность никогда не мешает...
III блок - есть ли у них корм, и притом осторожность никогда не мешает.. **( сложносочиненное. Сомневаюсь здесь, так как не знаю,  где начинается граница ССП ).**

Выходит, что в блоке может и ССП, правильно? Или я неправильно понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Мне вздумалось завернуть под **навес**, (2) где стояли наши лошади, **посмотреть**, (3) есть ли у них корм, (4) и притом осторожность никогда не мешает...

**Предложение 1:** Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, посмотреть. Здесь однородные сказуемые: *вздумалось завернуть, посмотреть.*

Это предложение является главным по отношению к придаточным предложениям 2 и 3.

Это СПП с двумя придаточными (определительным и изъяснительным), **параллельное подчинение.** Подчинительные союзы: союз ГДЕ и частица ЛИ в роли союза. Придаточные относятся к разным словам в главном предложении.

Между СПП (предложения 1, 2, 3) и предложением 4 **сочинительная связь,** присоединительный союз И ПРИТОМ.

Таким образом, можно считать, что здесь два блока: СПП и простое предложение.

Answer (score 3):

В этом предложении 2 блока:

1) Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, где стояли наши лошади, посмотреть, есть ли у них корм, ... - это сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя неоднородными придаточными;

2) ...и притом осторожность никогда не мешает... - простое предложение, которое присоединяется сочинительной связью к 1 блоку.

Связь в предложении союзная - подчинительная и сочинительная.

Comment: Значит в блоке может быть и ССП? Так?

Comment: @Sharon, так ошибка или нет. Мне одно неясно: если есть сочинительная связь, так почему во втором блоке предложение не ССП, а простое?